# Devemos ter regras específicas para problemas de Programação Competitiva?

Tags: debate, comportamento, comunidade

Me deparei com algumas perguntas sobre problemas de computação competitiva. Os problemas vêm de sites como [URI Online Judge](https://www.urionlinejudge.com.br), [UVa](https://onlinejudge.org/), [Codeforces](https://codeforces.com/), etc.

#### Exemplo de perguntas:

- [Problema 1041 do URI - "Wrong answer (5%)"](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/486748/100)
- [Erro 5% URI C - 1047 - Tempo de Jogo com Minutos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/437645/100)
- [Erro URI Python - 2588 - Palíndromos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/262957/100)

Alguns desses sites são utilizados por Professores e Instrutores para trabalhos acadêmicos. Pessoalmente gosto de ajudar alunos empacados em problemas como esses, dito isso, vejo algumas questões a serem tratadas com esse tipo de pergunta:

1. Alguns usuários estão postando os enunciados originais completos aqui no Stack Overflow. Dependendo do site de onde eles copiaram isso é proíbido ou requer autorização do autor do problema.
2. Enquanto alguns sites como o URI permitem o compartilhamento de soluções originais na Internet, os Termos e Condições desses sites geralmente também proíbem a postagem de soluções completas em fórums (no caso do URI me parece que eles só proíbem soluções no próprio fórum deles).
3. Independente de questões legais, existe uma questão moral e uma linha tênue entre ajudar alunos vs postar soluções prontas. Principalmente sabendo que essas soluções podem rapidamente parar na primeira página do Google.

Dessa forma gostaria de propôr uma discussão sobre a melhor forma de lidar com essas perguntas:

1. Devemos permitir esse tipo de pergunta para começo de conversa?
2. O que fazer quando o usuário posta o enunciado inteiro de um problema? (Muito provavelmente sem autorização do autor).
3. Devemos permitir respostas completas para os problemas?

   3a. Em caso positivo devemos postar algum aviso quando a cópia de soluções vai contra os Termos de Uso do site original?

   3b. Em caso negativo o que devemos fazer em relação a respostas com soluções completas para os problemas?
4. Devemos ter tags próprias para esses problemas (E.g., `programação-competitiva`)?

Observação: Também tenho questões semelhantes sobre problemas de sites especializados em entrevistas técnicas (Codility, Leetcode e similares). Eu mesmo já trouxe discussões sobre minhas soluções para problemas de entrevistas aqui para o site no passado. Admito porém que isso pode abrir portas para usuários não tão bem intencionados. Talvez essa seja outra discussão válida para a comunidade.

Comment: A questão legal, dentro das nossas possibilidades deve ser tratada, eu nem sabia das limitações. A pergunta em si postada aqui, pra mim, deve ser tratada como outra qualquer, depende da qualidade da pergunta, depende da pessoa ter um problema específico, postado de forma clara, não está só querendo que alguém resolve, ela coloque o que ela tentou, é ok. Minha experiência é que o pessoal que posta isso tem o mesmo problema dos outros, não sabem o mínimo de programar e só seguem receitas de bolo. Não conseguem isolar seu problema por causa disso. Eles fazem exercícios, mas não entendem aquilo.

Comment: A *tag* não deve ter, é irrelevante para descrever o problema. Pior ainda se servir para achar um repositório se soluções prontas para testes desses sites. O que eu não gosto desse tipo de pergunta, mesmo bem feita, nem é a pergunta, é algumas respostas que aparecem. Infelizmente nem todo mundo sabe responder algo assim, ensinando e não dando a solução.

Comment: @Maniero, pois é. Eu também não sei direito como agir. A [primeira questão acima](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/486748/100) por exemplo me parece bem intencionada e o OP está quase lá. Deixei um comentário que com sorte deve ajudar. Porém concordo que as pessoas em média dão não respostas ou quebram as regras do site original. Para problemas um pouco mais complexos também pode ser difícil ajudar sem quebrar regras do *Judge* (as vezes você precisa postar a solução para saber o que está errado). Sobre a tag concordo contigo, percebi também que o SOen também não tem uma tag dessas.

Comment: Acho que as regras naturais do site já cobrem esses casos, não vejo vantagem em classificar desta forma. Se não tem problema pontual no escopo, fechamento. Se o usuário tentou resolver e empacou, ele é bem vindo a postar o MCVE e a comunidade ajudar no próximo passo. Já o mero enunciado, quase sempre é caso de fechar, por razões já discutidas (falta de problema específico, etc). Inclusive isso é orientado explicitamente em pelo menos uns 3 ou 4 documentos importantes (guia de sobrevivência, checklist, manual de como não fazer perguntas). Nova só a questão jurídica, que favorece o fechamento.

Comment: Para colocar um ponto extra também não sei como tratar o problema dos enunciados copiados. Definitivamente não acho que devemos permitir enunciados na íntegra ou *prints* dos enunciados completos (como é o caso de todas as perguntasa acima). Dito isso é difícil remover o enunciado sem estragar a pergunta :(.

Comment: Prints com texto (enunciado, código, etc) quase sempre não deve ser feito. Mas o texto completo do enunciado não vejo como um problema, na verdade, é possível que ajude, já que o erro pode estar na interpretação, porém o enunciado deve ser apenas um complemento, podendo ser um link apenas (minha opinião), então, obviamente, se a pergunta tiver apenas o enunciado copiado, ela deve ser fechada. Mas, se a pergunta estiver clara, o problema for bem especificado e mostrando a boa vontade/real tentativa do OP de a solucionar, esse tipo de pergunta não é um problema

Comment: Como escrevi antes, o enunciado não deve ser essencial pra pergunta, apenas um complemento, logo, se a cópia de qualquer conteúdo é proibida, basta editar e remover, se esse conteúdo for essencial pode ser troca por algo equivalente (por exemplo, uma pergunta relacionada a interpretação de uma imagem, a imagem é essencial ao problema, mas pode ser trocada por outra). Aproveitando, levanto outras dúvidas. Deve haver uma opção pra esse caso nas sinalização? Mesmo alterando, o conteúdo ainda existirá no histórico, legalmente isso ainda será considerado errado? Deve ser removido até do histórico?